# What does it mean for the derivative of a dot product to be a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

For   S = $a^tb$   where  $a$, $b$ are vectors in an n dimensional space

$dS/db$ = $a$ (mostly im missing something really obvious here)

What does it even mean for the derivative of a scalar function with respect to a vector to be a vector? Should it not be a scalar (which is the directional derivative of $S$ in the direction of $b$)?

Comment: It denotes the gradient, not the directional derivative.

Comment: How does the differentiation of $S$ with respect to $b$ equal the gradient? My understanding of gradient is that it is a vector field describing the direction of steepest ascent at each point. It should be agnostic to what i differentiate $S$ with respect to. What about $dS/da$?

Comment: It's just notation for the gradient of the function $S(b)=a^t b$. Given the formula $dS/db=a$ in the question, it seems to be understood that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are viewed as constants while $b_1,\dots,b_n$ are viewed as variables. But since you haven't told us anything about the context, it's a bit hard to tell for sure. If you have a function $S(a,b)=a^t b = \sum a_i b_i$ of $2n$ variables, it would be more appropriate to use partial derivative notation: $\partial S/\partial a = b$, $\partial S/\partial b=a$ (as often seen in mechanics with $p$ & $q$).

Comment: i really hope i can put it this time .. in a normal function $y = f(x)$ when i say $dy/dx$ i  know $dx$ is the small change in x direction and $dy$ is the corresponding small change in the y direction and how $dy/dx$ is the slope of the tangent at a given point. Let us just take 3-d space. a and b two vectors and S the surface defined by them. i'd be grateful if i could understand ∂S/∂a and ∂S/∂b in the same light. this is ∂S, this is ∂b and this is ∂a and this is how it turns out to be this gradient vector. thank you very very much in advance

Comment: You don't. It's just **notation** for the gradient vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S(b)=a^Tb = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$$

what happens if I perturb $b_1$? how will the value change?

$$\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial b_1}=a_1$$

The value of $S$ will change by $a_1$ for every unit change in $b_1$.

What about $b_2$?

$$\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial b_2}=a_2$$

The value of $S$ will change by $a_2$ for every unit change in $b_2$.

$\frac{d{S}}{d b}$ effectively encode all the information in each component in a single vector.

Edit:

I believe what are you looking for is directional derivative.

what is the rate of change of $S$ when I move along a non-zero direction $u$?

$$\nabla_u S = \nabla S. \frac{u}{|u|} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{S(b+uh)-S(b)}{h}$$

Here $\nabla S = \frac{dS}{db}$.

Comment: Should not the first element be multiplied by ∂b1/∂b and similarly for other elements to capture $dS/db$. We are looking at the unit change in $b$ not in every element  right?

Comment: what do you mean by capture $dS/db$?

Comment: Honestly, i dont know exactly. Takes me back to my original question. $dS/db$ is the change in $S$ by taking a slice of the function in the direction of $b$ and moving a unit on tangent in that direction which i thought should be a scalar. What does it mean for it to be a vector?

Comment: i really hope i can put it this time .. in a normal function y=f(x)y=f(x) when i say dy/dxdy/dx i know dxdx is the small change in x direction and dydy is the corresponding small change in the y direction and how dy/dxdy/dx is the slope of the tangent at a given point. Let us just take 3-d space. a and b two vectors and S the surface defined by them. i'd be grateful if i could understand ∂S/∂a and ∂S/∂b in the same light. this is ∂S, this is ∂b and this is ∂a and this is how it turns out to be this gradient vector. thank you very very much in advance

Comment: I have edited the answer, I think what you are looking for is directional derivative.